# How Do I Stop Text From Moving When Using .slideToggle?

Tags: jquery, html, css

My text is moving while using slide.Toggle. The very last sentence in the preview shifts when toggling. If I put a p element at the end of the preview then it doesn't do this but the downside is it creates a return that I don't want. I want the sentence to continue on where it should.

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".content").hide();
//toggle the componenet with class msg_body
jQuery(".heading").click(function()
{
jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(1000);
});
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="layer1">

<span class="heading">During the most violent shocks of the Typhoon, the man at the Pequod's jaw-bone tiller had several times been reelingly hurled to the deck by its spasmodic motions, even though preventer tackles had been attached to it—for they were slack—because some play to the tiller was indispensable.</span>

<span class="content">In a severe gale like this, while the ship is but a tossed shuttlecock to the blast, it is by no means uncommon to see the needles in the compasses, at intervals, go round and round. It was thus with the Pequod's; at almost every shock the helmsman had not failed to notice the whirling velocity with which they revolved upon the cards; it is a sight that hardly anyone can behold without some sort of unwonted emotion.</span></div>
```

CSS

```
.layer1 {
margin: 20px;
padding: 0;
color: #bfbfbf;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 1.2em;
/* [disabled]text-align: justify; */
}

.heading {
cursor: pointer;
text-align: left;
}

.content {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
clear: both;
text-align: left;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I want to read more about the ship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you will be able to achieve exactly what you want, i.e. slideToggle and keep both span elements inline. To animate the slide effect the animated span gets transformed into a block element, hence the observable text shift. No float (or inline-block for that matter) in the world will be able to mimmick the inline display that you prefer.

The easiest solution would be to replace the slide effect with a fade effect which works on inline elements:

```
jQuery(this).next(".content").fadeToggle(1000);
```

That will show/hide you content without messing up the layout.

Comment: I'm not sure what you changed. It looks exactly the same.

Comment: Yours is still shifting. The reason you don't see it is you just happen to have enough text in there where it doesn't happen in your example. Add few more words and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm. May I ask which browser you are using? It works fine in Firefox 10 and Chrome...

Comment: Actually, why you can see the text shifting when all that is changed is the element's opacity is beyond me. That is, if `fadeToggle` is used instead of `slideToggle`...

Comment: I see what is happening. I had it all in a contentContainer div that had text-align set to justify. Thanks!

Comment: The downside is I need justified text. Anytime I try to justify the text it starts shifting again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` after `<span class="heading">`

```
<span class="heading">During the most violent shocks of the Typhoon, the man at the Pequod's jaw-bone tiller had several times been reelingly hurled to the deck by its spasmodic motions, even though preventer tackles had been attached to it—for they were slack—because some play to the tiller was indispensable.</span>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6CT25/3/)

Comment: The paragraph no longer expands when I do that. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I don't want a line break.

Comment: @Tomm ah, yeah there is no really elegant way to do this. I thought he wanted to fix how the heading class was being pushed up with his code example.

Comment: I think fading is the only way to do it really. Note: I messed up my answer (put in `slideToggle` instead of `fadeToggle`). Corrected it just now.

Comment: @Tomm Fading does not stop the problem. Read the message I left you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a clearfix class to the containing element. Here's the clearfix class that I use from HTML 5 Boilerplate:

```
.clearfix:after, .receipt-share-btns:after, .tm-act-content:after {
    clear:both;
    content:".";
    display:block;
    height:0;
    line-height:0;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.clearfix, .receipt-share-btns, .tm-act-content {
    clear: both;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix, html[xmlns] .receipt-share-btns, html[xmlns] .tm-act-content {
    display:block;
}

* html .clearfix, * html .receipt-share-btns, * html .tm-act-content {
    height:1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that worked for me here was to remove the text out of my

tags. Text that isn't inside p tags shows up fine and does not shift.